# Using bash regexp to insert the contents of a file into another

Tags: regex, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I have a javascript file with a jquery function call:

```
$.getScript('/scripts/files/file.js');
```

I want to replace that line with the contents of the file at that path. This is the bash script I have so far:

```
cat public/scripts/old.js | sed -e "s/$\.getScript\('(.)+'\);/$(cat \1)/g"  > public/scripts/new.js
```

However, my regular expression and remembering the path does not seem to be working correctly. I get `cat: 1: No such file or directory`
 as it seems as if `cat` is being called on the number 1 (which should be the remembered portion of the regexp). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using `$()` inside double quotes, the shell is parsing the `cat \1`, stripping the backslash and trying to run `cat 1` to pass its output as part of the argument to sed.  Sed has a command (`r`) for reading a file, but the filename must be literal, and cannot be the result of previous sed commands (at least in standard sed, perhaps some implementations provide that ability).  `sed` is really the wrong tool for this.  You could do an awk solution, but it will be fragile.

Here's a possible perl solution (warning: fragile):

```
perl -ne 'if( $_ =~ /\$\.getScript\('"'(.*)'"'\)/ ) 
   { system( "cat $1" ) } else {print}' public/scripts/old.js
```

Comment: what if I use single quotes instead? and change the path passed to `getScript` to use double quotes?

Comment: sed has no mechanism for storing the string and using it as a filename.

Comment: stupid question, but is `perl` a bash command, a shell, or the perl language implemented in the bash shell?

Comment: perl is a separate command.  It is non-standard, but nearly ubiquitous.

Comment: Perl is an executable that Bash finds in the PATH. In this context, it is also a command with arguments being fed to the Bash interpreter. Contrary to popular belief, it is *not* non-standard; it is currently part of the [Linux Standard Base](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Languages/LSB-Languages.html#PERL).

Comment: @CodeGnome  Being in the LSB makes it standard in Linux.  It does not make it standard.